# Keylogger, Published by Microsoft

Tags: malware, attacks, virus

Is it possible for a malicious Keylogger to appear as "Published by Microsoft" in the task manager? (I do not mean if windows have a build-in keylogger)

Comment: generally, no. if the OS was otherwise hacked, anything's possible.

Comment: Please post a screenshot. Task Manager does not, by default, display anything about the publisher of a process, even in the "Details" tab. A program could certainly name itself "Published by Microsoft", but that wouldn't mean anything at all; the process name can be any valid file name (and the description and window title don't have any meaningful restrictions at all).